# Is it really risky to make your IBAN public?

Tags: banks

[I have already asked this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/90674/is-it-really-risky-to-make-your-iban-public) on "Personal finance & Money", but probably it wasn't the right community.

It seems that people are reluctant to give their [IBAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number) to strangers.

I saw someone downvoting an app only because it shows the IBAN in clear on the main screen.

Is this rational? What could someone do knowing your IBAN?

Comment: I'm not sure this is appropriate here, either.

Comment: Please do not cross-post. It's the weekend and responses are slower.

Comment: @schroeder I know that cross-posting is wrong, but based on the type of questions in that community, it seems that it wasn't the right one. I am going to cancel it from there soon.

Comment: It seems to me that, if there is a security issue, it has to be with some information systems and what they allow to do knowing the IBAN.

Comment: IBAN is just a form of your account number. Whatever can be done with that is your risk. I'm still not seeing an infosec angle here.

Comment: @schroeder do you think that experts in security for banks do not have an answer? And this is not a rhetorical question.

Comment: I'm saying that one does not need to be a banking security expert to address the question.